# <td> huge size trying to make it smaller

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to adjust a `<td>` from my website in a place, but I just can't adjust its size, making the website create a rollbar in the bottom leading to the right side because the `<td>` is exceeding the page's size.

The part in question is the "right-column" that is in charge of the tip, the horoscope and the download banner below.

I'm new with web programming and I'm having a lot of trouble configuring this website, since it's an existing old background from an extinct website, so it's very hard to update it to new techs. It's already been a miracle I made some things that were in Flash being "converted" to Javascript/CSS.

[image]

```
<table id="main_bloc" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; --darkreader-inline-border-bottom:#303436;" colspan="2" id="header_bloc" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);" data-darkreader-inline-border-bottom="">
                <div id="logo" onmouseenter="showNavbarSection(-1);"><a href="test.php" style="display:block; width:100%; height: 100%;"><img src="medias/images/winxie.gif" onmouseover="this.src='medias/images/winxie2.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='medias/images/winxie.gif';" style="width: 106%;height: 153px;top: 0px;left: 3px;position: relative;"></a></div>
                <table id="language_selector" onmouseenter="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="medias/images/lang_top.gif" id="language_selector_border" style="margin-bottom: -1px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_en_arrow.gif" onclick="showLanguages();" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_it.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_fr.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_es.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_de.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_pt.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_ru.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr name="other_language" style="display:none">
                            <td><img src="medias/images/menu_lang_button_img_tr.gif" id="language_selector_item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="medias/images/lang_bottom.gif" id="language_selector_border" style="margin-top:-2px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <table id="navbar">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td onmouseover="showNavbarSection(0);"><span id="navbar_section"><a href="././pages/NewsPage.php"><strong>News</strong></a></span></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<span id="navbar_star">★</span>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td onmouseover="showNavbarSection(1);"><span id="navbar_section"><a href="././pages/StoryPage.php"><strong>Story</strong></a></span></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<span id="navbar_star">★</span>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td onmouseover="showNavbarSection(2);"><span id="navbar_section"><a href="././pages/GamesPage.php"><strong>Games</strong></a></span></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<span id="navbar_star">★</span>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span id="navbar_section"><strong><a id="navbar_section" href="#Parents"></a><a href="././pages/ParentsPage.php">Parents</a></strong></span></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<span id="navbar_star">★</span>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td onmouseover="showNavbarSection(3);"><span id="navbar_section"><a href="././pages/FunzonePage.php"><strong>Fun Zone</strong></a></span></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<span id="navbar_star">★</span>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td onmouseover="showNavbarSection(4);"><span id="navbar_section"><a href="././pages/CommunityPage.php"><strong>Community</strong></a></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="navbar_subsections" style="display:none" id="navbar_subsection_0" onmouseover="showNavbarSection(0);" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/News/AnnouncementsListPage.php">Announcements |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/News/EventsListPage.php"> Events |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/News/ArticlesListPage.php"> Articles </a></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="navbar_subsections" style="display:none" id="navbar_subsection_1" onmouseover="showNavbarSection(1);" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/SummaryPage.php">Summary |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/CharactersPage.php"> Characters |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/WorldPage.php"> World Locations </a></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="navbar_subsections" style="display:none" id="navbar_subsection_2" onmouseover="showNavbarSection(2);" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Games/MainWinxAdvPage.php">Winx Adventure |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Games/MinigamesPage.php"> Mini-Games |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Games/WebavatarPage.php"> Web Avatar </a></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="navbar_subsections" style="display:none" id="navbar_subsection_3" onmouseover="showNavbarSection(3);" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/FunZone/MusicPage.php">Music |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/FunZone/VideosPage.php">Videos |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/FunZone/WallpapersPage.php"> Wallpapers |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/FunZone/MagazinesPage.php"> Magazines </a></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="navbar_subsections" style="display: none;" id="navbar_subsection_4" onmouseover="showNavbarSection(4);" onmouseleave="showNavbarSection(-1);">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Community/ForumPage.php">Forums |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Community/FAQPage.php"> FAQ |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Community/BugReportPage.php"> Bug Report |</a></td>
                            <td><a href="././pages/Community/ContactPage.php"> Contact us </a></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="submenu">
            <td colspan="2">
                <iframe style="width: 100%; position: relative; left:15" src="././pages/Iframes/HotLinks.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" data-ruffle-polyfilled=""></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="container">
            
            <td id="container_left_column">





















                <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 11px; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <iframe id="ranking_iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="pages/Iframes/Access_guests.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled=""></iframe>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td id="container_middle_column" style="vertical-align: top;">










                <img onclick="javascript:Previous();" class="previous" style="position: relative; top: 274px; left: 541px; cursor: pointer;" src="././medias/images/arrow_left.png" onmouseover="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_left_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_left.png';"><img onclick="javascript:Next();" class="next" style="position: relative; top: 274px; left: 625px; cursor: pointer;" src="././medias/images/arrow_right.png" onmouseover="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_right_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_right.png';"><table id="content_videobox" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">

                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="">

                            <td id="content_videobox_firstcolumn" rowspan="3">
                                <div id="content_videobox_iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" volume="0"><div class="ckin__player default ckin__overlay"><video class="file" preload="metadata" poster="././medias/images/Video_Thumbs/happy2021thumb.png" src="././medias/videos/Happy_2021.mp4" data-overlay="1"></video><button class="default__button--big toggle" title="Toggle Play"><i class="ckin-play"></i></button><div class="default__controls ckin__controls"><button class="default__button toggle" title="Toggle Video"><i class="ckin-play"></i></button><div class="progress"><div class="progress__filled"></div></div><button class="default__button volume" title="Volume"><i class="ckin-volume-medium"></i></button><button class="default__button fullscreen" title="Full Screen"><i class="ckin-expand"></i></button></div></div></div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="content_videobox_secondcolumn">

                                <h2>
                                    <span class="video-title" id="content_videobox_videotitle" style="text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #560027;">Happy New Year!</span>
                                </h2>
                                <p style="position:relative; top: 150px;">
                                    <span class="video-description" id="content_videobox_videotext" style="text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #560027;">2021 arrived. Your favorite Winx fairies and specialists are hoping it will be better than the last one. The witches? Not sure.</span>
                                </p>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr style="">

                            <td id="content_videobox_firstcolumn2">

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr style="">
                            
                            
                            <td id="content_videobox_secondcolumn2" style="text-align: center">
                                <span class="video-number" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: rgb(86, 0, 39) 1px 0px 0px; --darkreader-inline-color:#e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-color=""> 1/4 </span>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>







                <div id="content_mininews_frame">
                    <iframe id="content_mininews_iframe" frameborder="0" src="pages/Mininews/NewsContentV2.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled="">Browser not compatible.</iframe>

                </div>

                



            </td>



        </tr>

        
        <tr>
        <td id="container_right_column" style="vertical-align: top;">
                <div id="content_horoscope_iframe" style="position: relative;/* margin-left: 808px; */">
                    <iframe id="content_horoscope_iframe" frameborder="0" src="pages/Tips.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled="">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
                </div>
                <iframe style="position: relative;width: 705px;height: 219px;margin-left: -466px;margin-top: -91px;" frameborder="0" src="pages/Iframes/Download.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled="">Browser not compatible!</iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="footer">
            <td id="footer_content" colspan="2">
                <hr style="margin-top: auto; position: relative;">

                <div style="margin-top: auto; position: relative;">
                    <img id="footer_rainbow_img" src="http://onlinewinxclub.com/center-web/medias/images/rainbow_logo_small.jpg">
                    <p id="footer_text">Winx Club™ a series created and produced by Iginio Straffi and Rainbow S.r.l<br>
                        © 2011-2021 Winx Club Online - Unofficial WinxClub.com inspirated by the old official website
                    </p>
                </div>​

            </td>
        </tr>
        <script src="js/ckin.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cssrefresh.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to set td width in %

Comment: Nope, nothing changes

Comment: As a side note, this is not tabular data. As such tables are the wrong way to go in the first place. tables should only be used for styling purpose within e-mail templates. If you want to style your website in a table like layout, use CSS-Grid.